Not finding tfvc version control in azure devops
I am not seeing TFVC option in version control while creating a new project at dev.azure.com. Only git option is available. How to get TFVC option?

The screen your on is to create a project. Looks like the default repo for the project has to be Git based. Go ahead and finish creating the project, then you should be able to create TFVS repos after that. But of course, it's 2024. Get off TFVC as soon as possible.

@mason I am starting to learn asp.net, got a 2 year old video which was using tfvc, is it going down or bad? Thanks for suggesting and fast reply.

I agree with @mason: use Git instead of TFVC. Even Microsoft is using Git in most (or all) their projects, such as Windows and Office.

@FreeDragon If you got a tutorial that's 2 years old but still recommending TFVC, then I really question whether the tutorial is actually good or not. TFVC is dead. Git has won the source control wars. And even if it hadn't, TFVC is like using a Betamax tape in the era of Blu Rays.

I agree, there's no reason to start a new project using TFVC at this point. Microsoft has deprecated it and it hasn't received a feature update for around a decade now. Plus, you can only use YAML pipelines with Git.

Hi @FreeDragon, what's the latest state of the issue? Are you able to see TFVC repo option after disabling Disable creation of TFVC repositories in the organization settings?

Check this setting in your org:


the option is permanently off, means it cannot be toggled...but tfvc is still not visible.

Generally, you should be able to see Team Foundation Version Control when creating a new project after disabling Disable creation of TFVC repositories in the organization settings.
If you still can't create a TFVC repo, try to use REST API Projects - Create. You can use the following PowerShell scripts. Replace the placeholders with your actual values.
$token = "{PAT}"
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
$url="https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/_apis/projects?api-version=7.1-preview.4"
$body = @'
{
  "name": "{ProjectName}",
  "description": "{ProjectDescription}",
  "capabilities": {
    "versioncontrol": {
      "sourceControlType": "TfVc"
    },
    "processTemplate": {
      "templateTypeId": "adcc42ab-9882-485e-a3ed-7678f01f66bc"
    }
  }
}
'@
$head = @{ Authorization =" Basic $token" }
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Headers $head -Body $body -ContentType application/json


As was mentioned by Shamrai Aleksander, you should have setting in repository tab that is on by default and should be turned off if you want to create project with TFVC in it.
Tho I would recommend to use git and avoid TFVC since it is really old system that has really small scope of use cases and even Azure DevOps trying to hide it now :)
